# How to update a specific array element with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Schema looks like:

```
var FriendSchema = new Schema({
  friend_id: String,
  gender: String,
  meta: {
    address: String,
    amount: Number
  }
}, { _id : false });

var GroupSchema = new Schema({
  unique_id: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  friends: [FriendSchema]
});
```

So a `Group` contains an array of `friends` and a `friend` has a `meta` with some information in it. I want to update a specific `friend` in the `group` that matches certain criteria. Here's what I've tried:

```
groupQuery = {unique_id: someId, 'friends.friend_id': friendNum, 'friends.gender': gender}
groupUpdate = {$set: {'friends.$.meta.address': myAddress, 'friends.$.meta.amount': debt}}

Group.update groupQuery, groupUpdate, (err) ->
```

What happens is the last `friend` in the group gets updated. Not the specific one that I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be just a typo, but `GroupSchema` uses `friends` and your code uses `friend`.

Comment: That was a typo - I fixed it. Same issue

Comment: The code looks fine, so if the last element of `friends` gets updated, then that element must match your query.

Comment: It's always the last element. Regardless of what I specify

Comment: Can you update your question to include sample docs that reproduce the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082804/trouble-updating-a-specific-subdocument-with-mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `$` in your update to identify the element that matches *both* properties in your query, you need to use `$elemMatch` in your query object:

```js
groupQuery = {
    unique_id: someId, 
    friends: {$elemMatch: {friend_id: friendNum, gender: gender}}
}
```