# Trouble updating a specific subdocument with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, subdocument

My document looks like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("52d317d7b5c4960000587cd4"),
  txid: "7e621eeb02874ab039a8566fd36f4591e65eca65313875221842c53de6907d6c",
  vin: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId("52d317d7b5c4960000587ce9"),
      meta_address: "321",
      meta_amount: 50,
      sequence: 4294967295,
      txid: "6749762ae220c10705556799dcec9bb6a54a7b881eb4b961323a3363b00db518",
      vout: 0
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId("52d317d7b5c4960000587ce8"),
      sequence: 4294967295,
      txid: "c04c413576307737f3ad48efe5d509ebc883e1d04822b3a2eccf6a80a4482932",
      vout: 0
    },
    {
      txid: "72d4fc43ac576a4b2f1f35e1b310a2d83a1012a36fdc7813ec237646950233cf",
      vout: 0,
      sequence: 4294967295,
      _id: ObjectId("52d317d7b5c4960000587ce7")
    }
  ]
}
```

My Query is:
`{ txid: '7e621eeb02874ab039a8566fd36f4591e65eca65313875221842c53de6907d6c',
  'vin.txid': 'c04c413576307737f3ad48efe5d509ebc883e1d04822b3a2eccf6a80a4482932',
  'vin.vout': 0 }`

and the update is:

```
{ 'vin.$.meta_address': '321',
  'vin.$.meta_amount': 50 }
```

But when I run it, it updates the first item in the `vin` array instead of the second. Now, oddly enough, if I change the query to:
`{ txid: '7e621eeb02874ab039a8566fd36f4591e65eca65313875221842c53de6907d6c',
  'vin.txid': 'c04c413576307737f3ad48efe5d509ebc883e1d04822b3a2eccf6a80a4482932'}`

then it works fine. I think the problem is that my query looks for 2 elements in the `vin`, but I need to search by both. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `$` in your update to identify the element that matches both properties in your query, you need to use `$elemMatch` in your query object:

```js
{ txid: '7e621eeb02874ab039a8566fd36f4591e65eca65313875221842c53de6907d6c', 
  vin: {$elemMatch: {
      txid: 'c04c413576307737f3ad48efe5d509ebc883e1d04822b3a2eccf6a80a4482932', 
      vout: 0 
  }}}
```